# Change flutter built_value json naming conventions

Tags: flutter, dart, built-value

I'm consuming an api that uses lowercase_with_underscores naming convention for its jsons' properties:

```
{
  "user_id": 0,
  "full_name": ""
}
```

and my built_value class is:

```
abstract class User implements Built<User, UserBuilder> {
  //...
  @BuiltValueField(wireName: "user_id")
  int get userId;

  @BuiltValueField(wireName: "full_name")
  String get fullName;
  //...
}
```

is there a way to change built_value serializer naming convention for all built_value classes so that it automatically asigns `my_property` in json to `myProperty` in built_value model instead of using `BuiltValueField(wireName: "my_property")` for each property?

Comment: I'd very much like to know the answer to this too. This has been a long standing issue for me as well